# Text flowing out of the comments area

Tags: bug, status-deferred

A user flagged a post letting us know about issues with the layout of the comments area which sometimes gets broken. I was able to reproduce the problem so here it goes. A screenshot bellow which shows the problem on the page where it was reported. And the first comment to this question is the text that seems to trigger the problem.

[image]

I was able to reproduce the problem both on Chrome (8.0.552.231) and Safari (5.0.3) on OSX (10.6.5).

Comment: Here's the [link to the post in question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1235). On Firefox (Windows Vista) I don't see this.

Comment: This is also WFM using Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.6, but gives the failing behaviour in Chrome and Safari on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Correct -- because the comment area is variable width (depending on whether votes are present, whether you are logged in, and how many votes there are), there is no way to prevent text from overflowing.

See here for more details:
[Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662)

Comment: At first I didn't understand your answer at all as I don't see this on Firefox 3.6. Maybe I got it from your link: You get the overspilling comments only for some browsers such as Opera and Chrome; for others it usually shouldn't happen. Can you please confirm if I got that straight? (And if yes, maybe add it to your answer?)